# Making a loop while inserting characters into a String?

Tags: java, string, loops

I was making a new code where my objective was to make whatever key you press make my little "truck" go forward.
I was trying to do this by adding spaces to my string, which was my truck.

```
String truck = "<o><o>-<o>~|#|¬";

    truck = new StringBuffer(truck).insert(0, " ").toString();

    System.out.println(truck);
```

I would like to know how to do a "loop" on this, where it add spaces with the quantity of keys that you pressed.
Thanks for reading, have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in a number of ways, for example...

You could attack the problem head on, for example...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(truck);
for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
    sb.append(0, " ");
}
truck = sb.toString();
```

You could write a method which produced an "empty" `String`

```
public String createPath(int length) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then simply append the result, for example...

```
truck = createPath(n) + truck;
```

Or you could be really tricky and simply use `String.format`...

```
public String createPath(int length) {
    return String.format("%" + length + "s", "");
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess it is gonna take me some time to understand what is going on with everything. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you lack a little experience with loops, consider taking a look at [Control Flow Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

This method generates the String you want to print. As you did not mention the way you want to listen to, it is omitted.

```
public String truck(int n) {
  String truck = "<o><o>-<o>~|#|¬";
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = n; i-->0;)
    sb.append(' ');
  sb.append(truck);
  return sb.toString();
}
```

The loop in more ordinary form is:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    sb.append(' ');
```

(I prefer the former when applicable, because the computation for `n` is done only once, and I have to specify the loop variable only once in the loop declaration.)

Comment: that is a very tricky for loop, had me double glancing that. Why not stick to the 3 part convention...

Comment: Although technically correct, you may want to tidy up your code (i.e. not using such a for loop, which the OP is unlikely to be able to understand) and also, add a summary as to *how8 it works.

Comment: ©Quirliom, ©ns47731: Thanks for the feedback, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into the nuances of capturing keypresses or any of that, you presumably just want a `while` loop to continue to "drive" your truck until the user quits (or whatever). A very simple one might look like this:

```
String truck = "<o><o>-<o>~|#|¬";
int count = 0;
while(true) { // This is your loop
    int n = 1; // or capture some user input, etc...

    // Then "move" the truck
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<n+count; i++) {
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    sb.append(truck);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    count = count + n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way:

```
public String truck(int countOfHits){
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<o><o>-<o>~|#|¬");
  sb.reverse();
  for(int i = 0; i <= countOfHits; i++){
    sb.append(" ");
  }
  return sb.reverse().toString();
}
```

If you think about it, you realize that this will turn an O(n²) solution into O(n).

Comment: You just made an O(n) solution O(n^2) and than back to O(n) with 3 times larger constant. ;) If you prefer to make it fast, preallocate the length for the builder and append the truck at the end.